# Width of ps output

Tags: bash, ps

I have used foreman to export an upstart config.  There are a lot of long environment variables so the processes started include some with a long command like:

```
-su -c cd /home/ubuntu/project/2014-03-05-3ff545d; export PORT=5000; export BASE_URL=http ..... ; command_to_run
```

However the ps output on a bash terminal is truncated and misses some of the exported environment variables and the `command_to_run` part on the end.  According to `man ps | grep Wide`:

```
w   Wide output. Use this option twice for unlimited width.
```

Using `ps aux -w -w` or `ps aux ww` or `ps auxww` still does not give me all of the command.

**Edit 1**

`htop` and `cat /proc/<PID>/cmdline` doesn't give the full output either, with the command truncated again to 4096 characters.

Answer (score 1):

Can you get all of the command easily? **No**. You can only if you want to recompile the kernel.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/199130/how-do-i-increase-the-proc-pid-cmdline-4096-byte-limit